# Identifying a monospaced programming font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I came across this font while looking at a Github Repo, and it looks quite similar to 'Monofur' in some aspects, but it's not the same. I tried using many online font identifying tools, but none of them worked. Here's the font I'm talking about:

[image]

I'm sure this is a monospaced programming font, but I have no idea what font it is. I've used WhatTheFont, Identifont, WhatFontIs. But none of them came up with good results. Saw the font originally at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/jaypei/emacs-neotree/imgs/neotree-1.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This must be [Fantasque Sans Mono](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans) by Jany Belluz.

It has the curved `i`, which is not *that* uncommon (coding fonts tend to accentuate differences in `i`, `1`, and `l`), but also the slanted straight quote `'` (quite uncommon) and very distinctive looped `k` (so uncommon that Jany added a stylistic set for those who apparently found it too "distractive"!).

[image: fantsque sans comparison]

Found using Google Images ("best monospaced fonts") – I concentrated on that loopy `k` and the italic `a`, which tends to be a mere slanted regular `a` in most coder's fonts  –, which led me to [The 100 Best Free Fonts for Designers](https://speckyboy.com/best-free-fonts/), where it ended up on the bottom position. (Quite undeservedly, I might add. I may have a new favorite!)